# Asignar un valor a una variable de vue mediante jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Tengo una plantilla con un range para asignar un rango de precio, al cambiar el rango de precio quiero mediante jquery cambiar el valor de las variables minPrice y maxPrice. He intentado mediante dos input, cambiar el valor con jquery y mediante un v-model hacer que ese cambio se translade a vue

```
            <div class="widget-content">
            <p>Price</p>
            <div class="price search-filter-input">
                <div id="slider-range" class="price-slider ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"><div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" ></div><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></span><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></span></div>
                <p class="amount">
                  <input type="text" id="amount" disabled="">
                  <input id="minPrice" v-model="minPrice">
                  <input id="maxPrice" v-model="maxPrice">
                </p>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Funcion jquery mediante la que cambio el precio

```
        var FilterPrice = function() {
        if( $().slider ) {
            $( function() {
                $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                  range: true,
                  min: 18,
                  max: 1000,
                  values: [ 18, 500 ],
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "$" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + "$" );
                    $("#minPrice").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
                    $("#maxPrice").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
                  }
                });
                $( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "$" + " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "$" );
            });
        }
    }; // Filter Price
```

Script vue con las variables data

```
<script>
const filtro = new Vue({
    el: '#filtro',
    data: {
        checkedBrands: [],
        checkedColor: [],
        minPrice: '',
        maxPrice: '',
    },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No usar `JQuery` con `Vuejs`, esto es mala praxis ya que pueden haber conflicto en el render del DOM. Si deseas cambiar el valor de tus inputs, utiliza el `v-model` de cada uno.

Mas información: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Saludos César, del enlace extrae un ejemplo, así evitamos que se pierda con el tiempo (algunos enlaces caducan)